# jquery not recognised.How to make to work the Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

my code is

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hello");
   });
   </script>
```

How to make to work the Jquery. Thanks.

update: "Hello" msg is not shown. Thanks.

Comment: try setting type="text/javascript" in script tag

Comment: It is already there as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be checking the path you have. The ~/ is parsed on ASP.NET server side controls, but not on normal HTML tags entered into a page. I think you want something like the following.

Traditional ASP.NET

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")%>"></script>
```

ASP.NET MVC Razor

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `~` symbol can represent the root of the website only when it is executed in the server. Use the following to replace the script include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")"></script>
```

Hope this would help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery script from CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise your code is okay
**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24x2B/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this may this work for you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```